# Windows : load csv file in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, kibana-5

I am running ELK on my machine. I want to load csv file in logstash so that I can visualize data in Kibana.

When I am performing command `bin/logastash -f D:/config/logstash_scaler.config` its giving following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_pair' for #<String:0xe82894>
Did you mean?  each_char
  paths= at D:/Java/Java Support/ELK/jruby-    9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:395
  setup! at D:/Java/Java Support/ELK/logstash-    5.5.2/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:52
  <main> at D:/Java/Java Support/ELK/logstash-    5.5.2/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:67
```

Here is my logstash config file

```
input{
    file{
        path => "D:/Java/Java Support/ELK/data/scalerloaddata.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        seperator = ","
        columns => ["Time","Host","load"]
    }

    mutate {convert => ["load","float"]}
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        index => "scaler"
        document_type => "scaler_series"
    }

    stdout{}
}
```

Comment: What version of Logstash and Java do you have?

Comment: You can use `/dev/null` on a windows machine?

Comment: @Val logstash 5.5.2

Comment: using /dev/null...can you please elaborate more